# Setting Windows System PATH Java

Tags: java, windows, path

(I know people are going to tell me this is a terrible idea, but the entire point of my application is setting the path.)

I want to make a Java app that involves getting and (permanently) setting the `%PATH%` variable.

Getting it is easy: `System.getenv("PATH")`

Setting it seems easy, using `Runtime#exec` and the `setx <variable> <value>` command from the command line. The problem is that setx truncates at 1024 bytes, and paths can easily balloon beyond 1024 characters.

Is there an alternate way to set the path (possibly using the JNI)? I know it's possible to *have* a longer path, because I do.

Comment: You could try `pathman` instead of `setx` or you could write the new value directly to the registry.  In the latter case you should read it directly from the registry as well, the value you get from `getenv` has been modified so feeding it back in may cause corruption.  (Variable references are expanded, and the user value and system value are concatenated together.)

Comment: I don't seem to have `pathman` installed on my system (Windows 10, if it helps.)

Comment: It's a Microsoft tool, it should be available from their download site.  Might be part of a larger bundle, but try searching on "pathman" and see what you find.